# Does SO store any data for unregistered users in the database?

Tags: discussion, unregistered-users

Or is everything saved in a cookie? I am aware that unregistered users are tracked by their cookies, but I think SO needs some reference to the owner of the question, and thus they must store some data?

Comment: They save quite a bit, including ip and such.

Comment: @drachmenstern, what is the point of storing the IP? How does it help? I mean it's not a reliable way of ascertaining identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unregistered users are essentially the same as registered users; the only big difference is their OpenID is a randomly generated GUID:

[image: Screenshot of an unregistered profile]

If they do decide to "register" the GUID is replaced with their actual OpenID, which will let them login in the future

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course.. Also because when they register they have all their old posts assigned to their account, so at the very least they have to save enough data to do that.